# Firebase Dynamic Links : weird URL prefix appearing on my account

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

As far as I know, I don't use Firebase Dynamic links for my project but I see this:

[image]

What is this weird URL ? Can I delete it safely ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're not using Dynamic Links in your App you can remove that integration from Firebase.
Simply select the three dots in the top-right corner, and select "Delete URL Prefix"

[image]